# java arraylist unending loop while size is set

Tags: java, lotus

I have this code, which is called only once

```
ArrayList<String> SendToEmails;
            SendToEmails = new ArrayList<String>();

            if(!environmentProduction){
                SendToEmails.add(EmailAccountForTest1);
                SendToEmails.add(EmailAccountForTest2);
            }else{
                SendToEmails.add(emailAccount);
            }

    SendToEmails.add("bla@bla.com");

for (int x = 0; x < SendToEmails.size(); x++) {
//send mail 
}
```

The code of above is a shortened snippet.. The SendToEmails size according to the log was 3. But my code ended in an infinite loop. And sent the same mail over and over again.

How would this ever be possible?

Comment: Do you manipulate `x` or `SendToEmails` within the loop's body?

Comment: It would help to see the body of that loop. If you're messing with `x` or changing the lists size while looping this could happen. Btw, is there a reason for not using an extended for aka foreach (i.e. `for( String address : SendToEmails) { ...}`)? (Using foreach would prevent you from messing with the loop variables and would throw an exception if the list was changed in the loop body).

Comment: Oh and a side note: if you want to make your own life easier and help us better help you then look up the Java code conventions and use them. That way your list would be named `sendToEmails`  and your test adress variables `emailAccountForTest1` etc. - i.e. variable, field, parameter and method names should start with a lowercase character to make them distinguishable from class and constructor names.

Comment: Indeed I was messing with the sendToMails variable, this fixed the error thank you Can you please put your comment in the answer so that I can mark it as answered thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think, you modify x in the loop. You can try next:

```
int sendToEmailsSize = sendToEmails.size();
for(int x = 0; x < sendToEmailsSize; x++) {
    //send emails and don`t change x
}
```

The size of emails list will be calculated only once, and not at each iteration of the loop. And if you change the list, the number of iterations of the loop will not change.

Also you can use forEach loop

```
for(String email: sendToEmails) {
    //sendEmail(email)
}
```

But if you can`t modify list in this loop. And if you are using multithreading, then if you change the list in another thread, you can get a ConcurrentModificationException if the loop has not yet ended.

And use variable names with a lowercase letter

Comment: Note that the first "solution" can give out of bounds exception if the list reduce of size and could skip items if some are added. So the solution is actually an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the loop as far as I can see. The information is insufficient to give an clear cut answer. But there are some things that we could do to understand the reason behind the problem and thus solve it.

- Try to print the size of the array list before the for loop
- Make sure that you aren't modifying the value of the variable 'x' inside the loop in                       such a way that it never satisfies the condition of the for loop.
- Try using for each loop if you are not concerned about getting the index directly.